# Error al conectarme al servidor Socket

Tags: javascript, nodejs

existe alguna manera de cachar si el servidor socket al cual intento conectarme está (apagado,no disponible etc..).

Este es mi codigo:

```
 import http from 'http';
 import socket_io from 'socket.io';
```

En el evento de mi botón

```
  try{

  var net = require('net');
  var client = net.connect(12346, 'localhost');
  client.setEncoding('utf8');

  client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("Recibiendo :", arguments)
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("Error al conectarme con el servido");
  });

  client.on('end', () => {
    console.log('desconectado del servidor');
  });

  client.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Conexion cerrada');
    });

}catch(error) {
  console.log("Error al conectarme con el servidor :"+error);
}
```

No tengo problemas cuando corro el servidor, pero si el servidor socket está detenido o no lo he iniciado no me muestra ninguno de mis logs y me app se corrompe mostrandome el mensaje:

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:12346 y
>
> TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect  [as oncomplete]

Comment: ¿Dónde se supone que usas socket.io?

Comment: mmm bueno uso el paquete net

Comment: *No tengo problemas cuando corro el servidor, pero si el servidor socket está detenido o no lo he iniciado no me muestra ninguno de mis logs*. Eso es perfectamente normal, es natural que no se muestre nada porque no levantas el servidor socket. ¿Qué tratas de hacer?

Comment: conectar java con node usando sockets, node es el cliente y java mi servidor

Comment: Ok. Levantas el server Java y ahora te conectas con el cliente Node. ¿Qué pasa aquí? ¿No conecta? ¿Ocurre un error? Básicamente dices: *Cuando trato de conectarme al servidor que aún no lo incio, no se muestran los logs*. Pero eso es perfecto normal porque si el servidor no está iniciado entonces el puerto está sin uso, no hay nada escuchando allí.

Comment: cuando levanto mi servidor Java no hay ningún problema hay comunicación con el cliente Node, si no ejecuto el servidor java y corro mi app de node esta se corrompe ... lo que necesito es mostrar un mensaje que dija error al conectarme con el servidor java. Saludos

Comment: Eso lo debes hacer con el evento `error`: `client.on('error', (err) => { ... });`.

Comment: Ok, lo checo... muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lo que necesito es mostrar un mensaje que diga error al conectarme con el servidor.

Eso lo debes hacer con el evento [`error`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error):

```
client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Error al conectarse al servidor', err.message);
});
```

Comment: Gracias, saludor

Comment: @Rastalovely De nada, me alegra te haya servido.